# How to place anchor in middle of div while same height as image?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to create a simple website, but my mind can't understand CSS placements inline and block elements.
I'm trying to place the anchor (`a`) element in the middle of the parent `div`, while being on the same horizontal line as the image (`img`).
See below for example.

I'd appreciate any help provided: that be a solution with a explaination or resources to better my understanding.

Thanks.

```html
<style>
 div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .info{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: wrap column; 
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .links{
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
</style>

<div class= info>
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
  <img src="IMAGE-SRC" alt="Picture" height=300px width=300px>
  <div class="links">
    <a href="">GitHub</a>
    <a href="">LinkedIn</a>
    <a href="">Instagram</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

Result getting:

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d9ymsrnf/2/)

```
   div
--------------------
|        h2        |
|                  |
|img               |
|        links     |
|       ....       |
--------------------
```

Wanted result:

```
   div
--------------------
|        h2        |
|                  |
|img    links      |
|                  |
|       ....       |
--------------------
```

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your `h2` is contained inside the flex box, and it is treated as a column. It should not be wrapped with the rest of the elemens.
Also, applying `flex-flow: no-wrap;` seems to work fine. no-wrap means show all columns on a single line.

```css
div {
    border: 1px solid black;
    margin: 1em;
  }
  h2 {
    text-align: center;
  }

  .info{
    display: flex;
    flex-flow: no-wrap;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  .links{
    flex: 1 1 0px;
    border: none;
    text-align: center;
    align-self: center;
  }
```

```html
<div>
  <h2>Welcome</h2>
  
  <div class="info">
    <img style="flex: 1 1 0px;" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/2/2f/Google_2015_logo.svg/368px-Google_2015_logo.svg.png" alt="Picture" height=300px width=300px>
    <div class="links">
      <a href="">GitHub</a>
      <a href="">LinkedIn</a>
      <a href="">Instagram</a>
    </div>
  </div>
   
</div>
```

Comment: How do I get the anchors to be horizontal equal to `h2` tag?

Comment: `flex: 1 1 0px;` on .links and img. edited the snippet accordingly